# JavaScript: How to define methods dynamically?

Tags: javascript

`Object.defineProperty` can be used to define properties and `getter` / `setter`s. But it doesn't seem to support setting properties that are functions (method). Why?

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'myMethod', function () {
    console.log('Hello!');
})
```

After this, `obj.myMethod` is `undefined`.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is always useful.

Comment: @Teemu It's worth mentioning that, despite MDN being a very good source, it should not be called *"documentation"*: anybody can edit that, like a wiki. Some MDN pages have mistakes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, I'm aware, I've contributed at MDN. MDN JS documentation is more or less the only _JavaScript documentation_, the ECMA Sript standard is not exactly a documentation. Or did you want me to write "RTFM" instead?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, we all know that MDN became the *de facto* documentation, despite its wiki nature. And no, I never advise "RTFM" or things like that, unless the F mean "fricking".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter you pass to `Object.defineProperty` should be an *object* with a *value* property, if you want to do something like this:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'myMethod', { value: function () {
    console.log('Hello!');
}})
obj.myMethod();
```

This would throw if you tried to pass a non-function:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'myMethod', 'foo')
```

But functions are objects too, so in your original code, the `defineProperty` call silently fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```js
var obj = { c: 3 };
obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {
    a: function(){
        console.log("testing");  
    }
});

obj.a();
console.log(obj.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding some points

Syntax : Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)

**obj** The object on which to define the property.

**prop** The name or Symbol of the property to be defined or modified.

**descriptor** The descriptor for the property being defined or modified.

```js
const obj = {};

         Object.defineProperty(obj, 'myobject', {
            value: 20,
            writable: false
         });
         obj.myobject = 10;

         document.write(obj.myobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). I recommend you to read the issues related with creating dynamic functions before actually implementing one.

This aside here is an example:

```js
function testMe () {
  var obj = {}
  obj.myFunc = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
  var el = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = obj.myFunc(1, 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="testMe();">Try</button>
```